# How to get only 15 repositories from GitHub API?

Tags: git, github, github-api

As my title stays, how to get only a limited number of repositories from the public API? I'm using the following link:

```
https://api.github.com/repositories //Gets 100
```

To get first the 100 repositories but I only need to get 15. This what I tried:

```
https://api.github.com/repositories?per_page=15 //Gets 100
```

It seems that adding `per_page=10` doesn't work at all. I have also tried:

```
https://api.github.com/repositories?since=369&per_page=15
```

Without any luck. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub Api doc says:
Note: Pagination is powered exclusively by the since parameter. 
see https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-all-public-repositories

The `per_page` parameter is not supported.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer but it does not answer my question. How to get only 15 elements from GitHub API? I don't want all 100. Is this even possible?

Comment: No way, it seems.